# Why execution time of integration tests have dramatically increased in Spring Boot 2.2?

Tags: java, spring, performance, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I have spring boot application and `100` integration tests there. My application consists of the following test dependencies:

1. junit 4
2. junit jupiter 5.3
3. spring-kafka-test for embedded Kafka
4. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/it.ozimov/embedded-redis for embedded Redis
5. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.zonky.test/embedded-database-spring-test for embedded PostgreSQL

All test classes inherit from `Base` class:

```
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@FlywayTest
@AutoConfigureEmbeddedDatabase
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, properties = {"spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true"})
public abstract class BaseTest {

}
```

For example, there is such test class:

```
public class Test1 extends BaseTest {

    @Test
    void test1() throws Exception {

    }
}
```

My application uses gradle. So, I have such `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.2.0.M4'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.boxfuse.client:gradle-plugin-publishing:5.2.1"
    }
}
```

I detect, that execution time of integration tests have dramatically increased from **2.2.0.M4** to **2.2.0.M5**. So, I brute force several spring boot versions and measure execution time of 100 integration tests. In this tests I just change `springBootVersion` value and reload gradle configuration.

- 2.2.0.M3 - 75 seconds
- 2.2.0.M4 - 74 seconds
- 2.2.0.M5 - 113 seconds
- 2.2.0.RC1 - 126 seconds
- 2.2.0.RELEASE - 120 seconds
- 2.2.1.RELEASE - 121 seconds

Note, that my test results is reproducible. I mean, each test run can have different result, but execution time changes for a few seconds (for each spring boot version).

I cannot understand, what is going on?

Upd. I create a bug ticket - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/18951

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](/help/mcve) that demonstrates the tests slowing down? That may allow someone else to identify the cause. Failing that, you could try to narrow things down yourself and update the question with your findings. There are a lot of moving parts here. For example, by upgrading from Spring Boot 2.2 M4 to 2.2 M5, you have changed versions of Spring Boot, Spring for Apache Kafka and Kafka. There are other version upgrades that may be involved too but it's impossible to say without a complete picture of your tests.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson hello, So, I fix the problem. I set `consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MAX_WAIT_MS_CONFIG, 10);` for test consumer, and tests have became as fast as before.I don't know why. The default value is `500` in both versions. It seems, that in `2.2.0.M4` we wait for ~10 ms for new records, and in `2.2.0.M5` we wait for `500 ms` (default max value). So, each my kafka test has increased for ~500 ms in new version.

Comment: We switched from kafka-clients 2.2.1 to 2.3.0 in M5; perhaps the internals changed there.

Comment: I just ran some tests and see no difference between 2.2.1 and 2.3.0 (a few more than 500 ms between Fetcher Sending and Fetcher Fetch logs). `logging.level.org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher=debug`. Is it possible that you increased `min.fetch.bytes` at the same time that you moved to M5? (Doesn't sound like it given the info provided in your question). I would be interested in seeing a small test case that exhibits this behavior so I can figure out what's going on.

Comment: @GaryRussell hello, nope, I just changed spring boot from 2.2.0.M4 to 2.2.0.M5, and tests were become slow. To fix this problem, I change `FETCH_MAX_WAIT_MS_CONFIG` to `10 ms`. 

I will try to create a small test case that exhibits this behavior.